# Removing "Loading..." from PFQueryTableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

After upgrading my Parse Library for iOS (obj-c) to v. 1.7.1 I got rid off the old activityIndicator that showed up every time the tableview was initializing. 
 INSTEAD I now got a black text in the center (x,y) of the tableview and I cannot remove it. The text says "Loading...".

Does someone now a trick like [this](https://parse.com/questions/customize-loading-message-text-colour-in-pfquerytableviewcontroller) in the old version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Just for others in the same situation**

In parse's SDK v1.7.5 the "loading..." is customizable via the storyboard. Just click on the PFQueryTableViewController and set the "Loading view.." in the Attributes Inspector.